# What is the regex expression that will add some character after my match.Value

Tags: c#, regex, wpf, linq

I have a code below in a linq expression, the problem is that if i used match.Value, it just print the match character, what I want is to print that match character plus 30 characters after.
You can see some of my approach in comment tag, which print nothing since I have the the condition where !regexis.match

```
foreach (var errorModel in from Match match in Regex.Matches(line, @"<(?!/)[^<]*?>\s+")
                                       where !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"<.+?/>")
                                       select new ErrorModel
                                       {
                                           LineNumber = lineno[0],
                                           ErrorMessage = "Check space after opening tag.",
                                           Text = match.Value
                                           //Text = Regex.Match(line, @"\D{10,30}<(?!/)[^<]*?>\s+").Value
                                       })
            {
                ErrorList.Add(errorModel);
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Text retrieval can be done:

```
Text = line.Substring(match.Index, Math.Min(line.Length - match.Index, 30))
```

You need to look into original line, as You can not (easily) have overlapping matches.

The where condition is suspicious. You really want to skip all lines containing closing tag?

Answer (score 0):

What about that regex:

[`<[^<>/]*>\s+.{0,30}`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%3c%5b%5e%3c%3e%2f%5d*%3e%5cs%2b.%7b0%2c30%7d&i=%3ctag%3e+++++++Hello+World)

It matches your tag any whitespaces and up to 30 other characters. There should no need for `where !Regex.IsMatch(line, @"<.+?/>")`.